# Gears - dynamic factor $K_v$

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, dynamics

I am trying to understand what the dynamic factor $K_v$ describes. I know that a low $K_v$ factor results in quieter and smoother work of the gear but what exactly does $K_v$ tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic%20factor%20gear%20agma) for this actually returns pretty good information.

- "The dynamic factor $K_v$ accounts for internally generated gear tooth loads which are induced by non-uniform meshing action (transmission error) of gear teeth."
- "It provides allowance for overload effects generated by a pair of meshing gears"
- "It is used to account for the effect of tooth spacing and profile errors..."

---

**Summary:** It is a way to account for transmission errors. Transmission errors occur due to:

- Inaccuracies in the manufacture of the gear (gear teeth are never perfect).
- Meshing of the gear teeth during action (vibration due to tooth stiffness during meshing, tooth friction, tooth wear etc.).

The gear ratio will fluctuate during operation because of these transmission errors. Therefore, the gears will always experience slight accelerations/decelerations causing dynamic forces - hence it is called a 'dynamic factor'.

There was a change to the way it was defined (reciprocated) by AGMA. The recent standard is that the factor should be above 1. Note that if $K_v = 1$ this represents perfectly accurate gearing. Under 1.1 is "very accurate gearing".

Hope that helps.